# Sublime Ruby Debugger—connection error with rspec

Tags: ruby, debugging, rspec, sublimetext

I am about to code with SublimeText and I have installed the Ruby Debugger Plugin. Everything works fine, but if I want to debug some rspec's the debugger disconnects due to this error:

```
Debugger exception: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
    StackTrace: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/philipp/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Ruby Debugger/debugge/ruby_imp/ruby_debugger_connector.py", line 102, in reader_thread
            bytes = self.client.recv(4096)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

the spec file I am debugging looks like this:

```
1 | require_relative '../spec_helper'
2 |
3 | describe Parser do
4 |     before :each do
5 |         @parser = Parser.new '../../../file.txt'
6 |     end
7 |
8 |     describe '#new' do
9 |          it 'raises an error if no input file is given' do
10|             lambda { Parser.new }.should raise_exception ArgumentError
11|         end
12|     end
13| end
```

I have set a breakpoint at line 5, but the debugger never overcomes line 3. What could that be?

Comment: does it work if you're just trying to step through normal ruby files?

Comment: yes it does. It even works for the rspec, but just to a given point, than it aborts with the posted error